# Prolog- Not the expected Output

Tags: prolog

I have this fact that returns the descendants but it only returns if "ascendente" is father/mother of "descendente". What am I doing wrong?

```
%descendenteDir(homem,mulher,filho)
descendenteDir('Tywin','Joanna','Ser Jaime').
descendenteDir('Tywin','Joanna','Cersei').
descendenteDir('Robert','Cersei','Joffrey').
descendenteDir('Robert','Cersei','Myrcella').
descendenteDir('Robert','Cersei','Tommen').
descendenteDir('Kevan','Dorna','Lancel').

descendente(Ascendente,Descendente):- descendenteDir(Ascendente,_,Descendente)
    ;descendenteDir(_,Ascendente,Descendente)
    ;descendenteDir(descendente(Ascendente,_),_,Descendente)
    ;   descendenteDir(_,descendente(Ascendente,_),Descendente).
```

Answer (score 1):

The `descendente(Ascendente,_)` part in the final rule is not quite right. It should be something like this:

```
descendente(Ascendente,Descendente):- descendenteDir(Ascendente,_,Descendente)
    ;descendenteDir(_,Ascendente,Descendente)
    ;descendenteDir(X,_,Descendente), descendente(Ascendente,X)
    ;descendenteDir(_,X,Descendente), descendente(Ascendente,X).
```

It's not the same as calling functions and getting returned values in languages like C++/Python/Java. In Prolog, you have a set of facts (the `descendenteDir` rules at the top), and some inference rules (the `descendente` rule). In the definition where you would use the rule recursively, you would have to provide a variable which would be bound to the values available (from the facts). That variable would later be used to infer the subsequent rules. Here `X` is that variable. Prolog will bind different values to it and try to infer the next part from the following clause.

Comment: I tried the code but it only returns the children of the Ascendent

Comment: My bad, I didn't write a single line of Prolog code in ~7 years and forgot that Prolog variables should start with an uppercase letter. Fixed it.